# Vectorizing API Data Request in R

Tags: r, api, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize these data requests by creating a function and iterating through a series of years? I know how I would do it with a loop, but I am wondering if I can leverage the benefits of vectorization.

```
y_2015_2011 <- ct_search(reporters = "Canada", partners = "All", trade_direction = "all",
                     start_date = 2011,end_date = 2015,commod_codes = 030613)

y_2005_2009 <- ct_search(reporters = "Canada", partners = "All", trade_direction = "all",
                      start_date = 2005,end_date = 2009,commod_codes = 030613)

y_2010_2014 <- ct_search(reporters = "Canada", partners = "All", trade_direction = "all",
                      start_date = 2010,end_date = 2014,commod_codes = 030613)
```

Comment: Where does `ct_search` come from? You should be able to do this with something like `lapply(c(2011, 2005, 2010), function(x) ...)` and setting the end date to x + 4

Comment: This is from the package comtradr; so how would you structure the function?

Comment: `ct_search(reporters = "Canada", partners = "All", trade_direction = "all", start_date = x, end_date = x + 4, commod_codes = 030613)`